# JS get value of buttons in a dynamic grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

- Squares = Buttons with x = clicked, x = value

How do I create a textarea value onClick on a button that contains the value of each square AND empty values of anything that is not selected, 
i.e.

```
<textarea>x,&bnsp;,&bnsp; ,&bnsp;\n,&bnsp;x,&bnsp; ,&bnsp;\n etc.</textarea>
```

Basically the text output needs to reflect the values of the squares in plain text, that’s why I need empty values to create that “visual”.
The rows and squares in each row are also subject to being dynamically generated when the page loads, based on a default or changed value.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to get the value of the textarea? I don't really understand your question

Comment: yes, so the grid above basically shows buttons that are laid out. When you click the button it receives a "x" value, if they are left alone, they have an empty value. Now when you click a button on that page, it should translate those values into a new value the textarea. hope that makes sense.

Comment: So the grid above is buttons, and every time the button is clicked, you want the text to become an "x"? Is that all?

Comment: yea, the text of the button becomes x. and that x, plus others and all "empty values" (maybe a &nbsp; or something) for each button in that grid should be passed on to the textarea.

Comment: I posted an answer. Did that cover everything you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires a bit of jQuery, but this does what you want.

```js
var result = [];
var idnum;
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  result.push($("#" + i).html() + ",");
}
$(".result").html(result);
$(".button").click(function() {
  idnum = $(this).attr("id");
  $(this).html("x");
  result[idnum - 1] = "x,";
  $(".result").html(result);
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="1"> </button>
<button class="button" id="2"> </button>
<button class="button" id="3"> </button>
<br>
<button class="button" id="4"> </button>
<button class="button" id="5"> </button>
<button class="button" id="6"> </button>
<br>
<button class="button" id="7"> </button>
<button class="button" id="8"> </button>
<button class="button" id="9"> </button>
<br><br>
<textarea class="result">Result</textarea>
```